# apache cxf wss4j signature method dsa switch to rsa

Tags: security, soap, cxf, wss4j

i have litle problem with signature soap message with apache cxf framework in 3.0.4 version. I use wss4jOutInterceptor with configuration

```
<bean id="WSS4JOutInterceptor" class="sk.posam.risng.soa.mur.interceptor.security.WSS4JOutInterceptorCustom">
    <argument>
        <map>
            <entry key="action" value="Signature"/>
            <entry key="user" value="posam_ssl"/>
            <entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="DirectReference"/>
            <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                <ref component-id="passwordCallback"/>
            </entry>
            <!--tato property musi byt vyplnena inak sa nepusti podpisovanie sprav, avsak property su ulozene v cryptoHolder-->
            <entry key="signaturePropFile" value="seeCryptoHolder.properties"/>
        </map>
    </argument>
    <property name="securityEnabled" value="${security.enabled}"/>
    <property name="cryptoHolder" ref="cryptoHolder"/>
</bean>
```

here is my algorithm tag

```
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1"/>
```

and i would like use rsa algorithm, how can i configure this part,

tank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hash-function you want to use, you can select one of [several RSA algorithms](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-xmlsec-algorithms-20130124/#RSA). 
 For example, `http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1`.